# Change DataStructure (or maybe just a symbol) from JLink/Java program

Tags: mathlink-or-wstp, interoperability, external-calls, java, webtools

I try to use JLink and Java program for receiving responses from the abstract WebSocket server. WSS not supported by Wolfram Language now, but I can use [this java project](https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket) + JLink for the creating a WebSocket client - simple example of the client [here](https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket/blob/master/src/main/example/ExampleClient.java). In Wolfram Language I use this client as following:

```
Get["JLink`"]; 
ReinstallJava[ClassPath -> <classpath>, CommandLine -> <commandline>]; 
client = JavaNew["ExampleClient", JavaNew["java.net.URI", "wss://host:8888/stream"]]; 
client@connect[];
```

After this in Java console window printing messages from the server. Messages handling in the method [`onMessage(String message)`](https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket/blob/master/src/main/example/ExampleClient.java#L59). How can I change the class `ExampleClient` and method `onMessage` for the saving result in a DataStructure that created in Wolfram Language?

Dependensies in my environment for the standalone using:
Java ~17 (Default OpenJDK in Wolfram/System Files/Java not supported)
hamcrest-core-1.3.jar
[Java-WebSocket-1.5.2.jar](https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket/releases/tag/v1.5.2)
json-20211205.jar
junit-4.12.jar
slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar

All jar-files I got from maven repository

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've tested this code with Mathematica's default JDK (version 11.0.12, Mathematica 13.0.1).

Assume I've run an echo server on `127.0.0.1:8000`.

Let's import `JLink` and have a variable to store our result:

```
Needs["JLink`"];

result = {};
```

Import `Java WebSocket`'s `jar` file:

```
AddToClassPath["C:\\Java-WebSocket-1.5.2.jar"];
```

Now, you need to define your extended class in `Java`, like:

```java
import com.wolfram.jlink.*;

import java.net.URI;
import java.util.Map;
import org.java_websocket.client.WebSocketClient;
import org.java_websocket.drafts.Draft;
import org.java_websocket.handshake.ServerHandshake;

public class ExampleClient extends WebSocketClient {

  // implement other methods
  // ...

  // send a string on opening
  @Override
  public void onOpen(ServerHandshake handshakedata) {
    send("Hello from java");
    System.out.println("opened connection");
  }

  // manipulate Wolfram variable on receiving message
  @Override
  public void onMessage(String message) {
    KernelLink link = StdLink.getLink();
    if (link != null) {
        try {
            link.evaluate("AppendTo[result,\""+message+"\"]");
        } catch (MathLinkException e) {
            System.out.println("Failed");
            link.clearError();
            link.newPacket();
        }
    }else{
        System.out.println("Null");
    }
  }
}
```

I couldn't find an easy way to access a defined class, so apply `ExternalEvaluate` to the above string (`"` needs to be escaped) and save the output in a variable, like:

```
temp = ExternalEvaluate["Java", ... ];
```

Now, the following code will manipulate the `result` variable in the Wolfram session:

```
client = JavaNew[temp, JavaNew["java.net.URI", "ws://127.0.0.1:8000"]]
client@connect[]
```

Checking our variable:

```
result

(* Out: {"Hello from java"} *)
```

For better debugging (seeing `System.out.print`), show the console with:

```
ShowJavaConsole[]
```

For further information read [Requesting Evaluations by the Wolfram Language](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/JLink/tutorial/CallingJavaFromTheWolframLanguage.html#4680).

Comment: Thank you @ben-izd!